# Thyme leaf not working ${name} shows in html

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to output html which has been processed by thyme leaf, so values like ${name}, ${address} whatever - will be filled in.

But what is actually happening, is the templateEngine is splitting out html that seems to be actually the same as it went in.

Mainly following this [tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-sending-email-thymeleaf-html-template-example/) from memorynotfound.com

Here is my **ThymeleafConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(StandardTemplateModeHandlers.HTML5.getTemplateModeName());
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        emailTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }
}
```

My method **where I'm calling templateEngine**

```
@Component
public class ThymeleafEngine {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    Email email = new Email();

    public String process () {   
        Map model = new HashMap();
        model.put("name", "Bob");
        email.setMap(model);

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(email.getMap());

        templateEngine.initialize();

        String html = templateEngine.process("email_template", context);

        return html;
    }
}
```

**Email object**

```
public class Email {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Map map;

    public Map getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

I can't fit anymore code in this post, but the html is pretty basic only difference is with the ${name} inside a `<p>` tag.

Comment: Do you have your HTML file in the `templates` folder? This is the default location for Thymeleaf templates.

Comment: yep its in template folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p th:text="'Dear ' + ${name} + ','" />
```

needed to be in the html template and **NOT**

```
<p>Dear ${name}, </p>
```